# If $A$ and $B$ are respectively positive-definite and positive-semidefinite matrices, is $A^T B A - B \ge 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I would like to prove that $A^T B A - B \ge 0$ for given $A > 0$ and $B \ge 0$.

Comment: Of course not : you can take $A$ small ... Could you elaborate conditions ?

Comment: Show your work also.

Comment: Thanks. If matrix $B \ge 0$ is given, for which matrix $A$ the inequality is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Consider the 1 by 1 matrices $A$ with $0< A < 1$, and $B \gt 0$. Then $A^TBA - B < 0$